Cookie is not setting in a https browser
i am doing a  google login , then passing a jwt token in the form of cookies to the frontend broswer
this token is used by the middleware to pass in to the secured routes
the main problem is , the token is set as a cookie in the localhost , and frontend backend code is running fine
but when i am shifting to developmental https environment with both the frontend and backend ,
then my backend is producing the jwt , but my frontend is not showing up the token in the cookies section
i am using next js as my frontend
my login code
import { Router } from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import User from '../models/User'; // Ensure this path is correct for your project structure
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import cookie from 'cookie';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();



const router = Router();

//router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

router.get('/creator', passport.authenticate('google-content-creator', {
  accessType: 'offline',
  prompt: 'consent',
  scope: [
    'profile',
    'email',
    // Add any other scopes needed for YouTube here
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'
  ]
} as any));



router.get('/google/redirect', passport.authenticate('google-content-creator', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    const { googleId, email, name } = req.user as any; // Type casting for simplicity

    try {
      // Check if the user already exists
      let user = await User.findOne({ googleId });

      if (user) {
        user.isContentCreator = true;
        await user.save();
      } else {
        user = new User({ googleId, email, name, isContentCreator: true });
        await user.save();
      }

      // Create a token object
      const tokenData = {
        _id: user._id,
        email: user.email,
        googleId: user.googleId,
        name:user.name
      };

      const tokenSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET as string
      const token = jwt.sign(tokenData, tokenSecret, { expiresIn: "1d" });
      console.log("token",token)

      // Set token in cookies
      res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('token', token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 // 24 hours
      }));
      const creatorId = user._id
      console.log('Redirecting to dashboard of content creator...');

   

      res.redirect(`${process.env.CREATOR_CLIENT_URL}/${creatorId}/contentCreatorDashboard`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error handling user login:', error);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('User authentication failed, redirecting to login...');
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});





export default router;

my middleware code  , in the frontend
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const cookieData = cookies().getAll();
  const token = cookieData.find(cookie => cookie.name === 'token')?.value;
  const path = request.nextUrl.pathname;

  // Adjust the paths as needed
  const isPublicPath = ['/login', '/signup', '/verifyemail'].includes(path);

  if (!token && !isPublicPath) {
    // User is not logged in and trying to access a protected route
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url));
  }

  // If the user is trying to access login-related routes but is already authenticated
  if (token && isPublicPath) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/fetchUser', request.url));
  }

  // Allow the request to continue
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    `/:path*/contentCreatorDashboard`,
    `/login`,
    `/signup`,
    `/verifyemail`,
    `/test`,
    `/:path*/campaigns`,
    `/:path*/campaigns/campaignAnalytics/:path*`,
    `/:path*/leaderBoard`,
    `/fetchUser`,
    '/:path*/leaderBoard/:path*'
  ], // Adjust based on your route requirements
};

i am expecting the token to show up in the application-cookie section of the browser , so that my middleware can read it and can pass so that i can get redirected to my secured routes

try using httpOnly:false

A cookie that isn't explicitly set with httpOnly : false will not be accessible through document.cookie in the browser.
That's why your middleware doesn't works in https environment where the server set httpOnly:true.
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('token', token, {
      httpOnly:false,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 // 24 hours
}));

Note: You can't set it to false unless you have a very good reason to be able to access cookie through client JS.

so if i set it to false , then my browser will be able to access it ?

obviously, your browser will do
